# Why java.net.URI isAbsolute() method return true for an URI that have fragment?

Tags: java, uri

My goal is to follow the term of `absolute-URI = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ]` from Appendix A. Collected ABNF for URI from [RFC3986]

My understanding that is `absolute-uri` can't have `fragment`. I tested it with `java.net.URI`. I checked that `isAbsolute() method` only check for the scheme != null instead of checking the entire String.

My expected result was that the URI's isAbsolute() method return:

1. false for Uri `http://wwww.example.com/index.html#Related` because it has fragment.
2. true for Uri `http://www.example.com/index.html`.

My actual result was that the URI's isAbsolute() method return true.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInstance;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class RegExTest {

  @Test
  void validAbsoluteUri() throws URISyntaxException {
    URI uri1 = new URI("http://www.example.com/index.html#Related");
    Assertions.assertEquals(false, uri1.isAbsolute());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The BNF in appendix A does not tell the entire story.  If we read the entire specification, in particular [section 4.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-4.3), we see:

> **Some protocol elements** allow only the absolute form of a URI without
> a fragment identifier.  For example, defining a base URI for later
> use by relative references calls for an absolute-URI syntax rule that
> does not allow a fragment.
>
> absolute-URI  = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ]

(Emphasis mine.)

*Some protocol elements* use that form of absolute URI.  `http` and `https` are not among those protocols, [except when used as a base URI](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-5.1).

Notice that [the general syntax](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3) allows absolute URIs with fragments.